# Automate click of button present in a different webpage in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var openwindow = window.open("http://www.google.com/");
var id = openwindow.document.getElementById("IdOfAButonInThatWebPage")();
 alert(id)

}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">

</body>

</html>
```

Here I'm trying to find the ID of the button that is present on a different page. for testing purpose, i'm just displaying an alert for the ID. but i'm unable to see the alert. Once we get teh ID of the button, is there a way to automate the click of that button and close the webpage? Please help.. thanks

Comment: Is the different page on same server or different server ??

Comment: It is on a different server. Basically, the idea is to login to a portal without opening it.

Comment: If its on a different server, I am afraid you cannot do what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to open an in memory version of another web page.
The only way another page could be available on the current page would be to use an iframe. However, accessing the DOM of the target page wont work if it is located on a different domain.